# How to translate MainMenu using TLang in RAD studio?

Tags: c++builder, rad-studio

I'm creating a pretty simple app in RAD studio 10.3, c++ builder. I've decided to add languages support. I found the TLang component - it was exactly what I wanted. It works fine for all "on the form" components like Edit, Label, CheckBox, etc. But it doesn't work for the main menu (TMainMenu). It just doesn't react to language switches.

Switches are done this way

```
void __fastcall TForm1::EnLang_menuClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    LoadLangFromStrings(Lang1->LangStr["EN"]);
    // Lang1->Lang = "EN"  // I tried this way - same result
}

void __fastcall TForm1::RuLang_menuClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    LoadLangFromStrings(Lang1->LangStr["RU"]);
}
```

My guess is TLang only checks controls for strings switches, but TMainMenu isn't a child of the TControl. Anyway - how to translate a main menu using TLang? Sure, I can write something like TLang myself and make it translate any components I want, but it needs time, so I was looking for something ready to go now.